# MVC Routing config: URL Pattern with a mixed Segment and defaults

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have the following routing configuration under a MVC sample project:

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.MapRoute("", "X{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Customer", action = "List" });

        routes.MapRoute("MyRoute", "{controller}/{action}",
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    }
}
```

I redirect all controllers (Home, Customer) to the same view that displays the Current controller and action name.

So, for the URL `http://localhost:5O44O/XCustomer` I have the following output:

> The controller is: Customer
>   The action is: List

I expected that for the URL `http://localhost:5O44O/X` I should have the same output... But this is not the case...

> ### Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you
>   are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed,
>   had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review
>   the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>
> Requested URL: /X

Why that? I placed the "X" condition first, so I should obtain the default replacements with Customer and List ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You a are receiving `404 error`, because you don't have `XController`. If you have it, you'd receive route: `http://localhost:5O44O/XX`

`routes.MapRoute("", "X{controller}/{action}"` - this is just a syntaxis to generete string of route. And it doesn't have a behavior you were expected.

All manipulations should be done here:

```
new { controller = "Customer", action = "List" });
```

If you want to have such route: `http://localhost:5O44O/X/List` you need to write your MapRoute as follows:

```
routes.MapRoute("name", "X/{action}",
            new { controller = "Customer", action = "List" });
```

You may even write:

```
routes.MapRoute("name", "HelloBro",
                new { controller = "Customer", action = "List" });
```

It will return you route `http://localhost:5O44O/HelloBro` for your `List action` of `Customer controller`

Comment: I don't have the `XController`, nor I have the `XCustomerController`, but when I have an X the routing configuration should identify that case and take the default values for controller (Customer, in my case) and action (List, in my case). This is why, by eg. the link `http://localhost:5O44O/XCustomer` works well.

Comment: @Serge Route, that you have written expects controller name, because of {controller} statement. Try to change route as in my answer and you'll get, what you want.

Comment: that behavior is not very clear to me... The route I have written *or* expects the controller name, *OR* should use the default one I provided (Customer). What I don't understand is why this **default** controller is not used. Also, I don't want the `X/BlaBla`, I want `XBlaBla` (using the same routing segment)

Comment: And, I believe you have reason, I could use `routes.MapRoute("name", "X", new { controller = "Customer", action = "List" });` this could make the desired stuff... but I just wonder why the route with default values does not work as expected....

Comment: @Serge I think that is because both your routes are expecting for Controller name. Runtime doesn't understand where to map, when you write just http://localhost:5O44O/X it tries to find "XController"